# Laravel 4 search a model through a form

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I used Jeffrey Ways Generator to generate some codes via the scaffold commands.
I am very new to OOP, Frameworks and Laravel. I have a working method but just want to know if it's the right way to do it.

So basically I want a search my models via an input box.

In my index.blade.php of the model I have this code at the top of the page.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tweets/', 'method' => 'get')) }}
   {{ Form::text('id') }}  
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now in my tweets controller I have this

```
public function index()
    {
        if(Input::get('id'))
        {
           return Redirect::action('TweetsController@show', array(Input::get('id')));
        }

        else 
        {

        $tweets = $this->tweet->all();
        // print_r($tweets);
        return View::make('tweets.index', compact('tweets'));
        }
    }
```

Everything works as I want it to work, but is this the right way of doing things?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to `show()` from the `index()` method if Input::get('id') is set, you should submit the form directly to the `show` method by changing the URL.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tweets/show/', 'method' => 'get')) }}
   {{ Form::text('id') }}  
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Make sure to set up a route to tweets/show/ too in `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/tweets/show', 'TweetsController@show');
```

---

**Possibly a better solution:**

If the form exists only as a link to show a specific tweet (by the ID), it's better to set up the route and `show()` method as:

```
Route::get('/tweets/show/{id}', 'TweetsController@show');
```

and then change the `show()` function in your `TweetsController` file to:

```
public function show($id)
{
   // Load the tweet using $id as ID instead of Input::get('id')
}
```

Since then you can link to it just by making a normal link (with the ID in the URL):

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('tweets/show/'.$tweet->id) }}">View tweet</a>
```